# AppImage - Where is state saved between instances?

Tags: appimage

If you're running an [AppImage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppImage) application, and you make settings changes to it (or anything else that would change the state of the application), are those changes saved within the AppImage file itself? And if so, how do you preserve those settings upon upgrading to a later version of that AppImage application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not stored within the AppImage file itself. At least in Ubuntu, AppImage usually stores configurations and settings for each app in one of these directories:

```
/home/user/.config/the_app_name
/home/user/.the_app_name
```

The [AppImage README](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit#special-directories) has more information.:

> ### Special directories
>
> Normally the application contained inside an AppImage will store its
> configuration files wherever it normally stores them (most frequently
> somewhere inside `$HOME`). If you invoke an AppImage built with a recent
> version of AppImageKit and have one of these special directories in
> place, then the configuration files will be stored alongside the
> AppImage. This can be useful for portable use cases, e.g., carrying an
> AppImage on a USB stick, along with its data.
>
> - If there is a directory with the same name as the AppImage plus `.home`, then `$HOME` will automatically be set to it before executing the
>   payload application
> - If there is a directory with the same name as the AppImage plus `.config`, then `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` will automatically be set to it before
>   executing the payload application